# Where do I hide my login info when using PHP connect to get to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I need to connect to a `mysql database` using **`PHP`**.  I am storing my login, user, password, and other info in a separate php file (let's say `"mysql_connect.php"`) and then accessing it via require_once `(mysql_connect.php)` in a different file.

I have done a bit of googling and I know that I am supposed to keep "mysql_connect.php" out of the web root.  I have moved it outside of the html folder and tried calling to it by using "../../mysql_connect.php"   This is not working, it gives me an error "function not found" or something like that.  Upon googling that, the internet says that its because it can't locate the file i'm referencing.  When I move mysql_connect.php into a folder below root, everything works fine.  The issue is because it is moved outside of the web root (i think).

I have been googling for two days now and cannot find a detailed explanation on how to get this to work.  Something about changing the .htaccess file?  I've read a bunch of articles on the theory but I am really looking for a step-by-step tutorial (I am a beginner).  The only step-by-step tutorials I can find just tell you to put the config.php file into the same folder which is not secure.

Also in reading, it says that putting mysql_connect.php above root might not be THE most secure way to store the information as it is still basically just a .txt file and it can be retrieved easily(like downloading it).  I am looking for a balance between secure and also do-able (for a beginner like myself).  The mysql database I am trying to protect will not have any personal information and I plan on using a dedicated server (with no other information on it).
Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Is your PHP interpreter / webserver confined with a tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)? Any of these [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tools can prevent loading your specified file, and where you place the file might be important to the security policy in place. Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `dmesg(1)` output for likely-looking error messages.

Comment: this sounds like a lead.  the server i am using currently is in fact a shared server.  how do i find out if i am confined with one of those tools?  i have poked around and cannot find var/log/audit. At any rate, if this is the case, how do i go about hiding my connect.php file so it is not so blatantly public?  Thank you so much!

Comment: I've been curious about the best practice here, as well. I put my connect php in a subdirectory under webroot, with an empty index.html file (to prevent the dir from ever being listed) and with a large numeric name (to keep it from being guessed).

Comment: @Jim what's wrong with with having this file without index.html and without  a large numeric name?

Comment: PHP is an evaluated Hypertext Pre Processor (It compiles the code on the fly), and will not be visible to people going to that specific file. As long as the code is within `<?php` and `?>` it won't show to the client. Unless the webserver isn't properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

> it gives me an error "function not found" or something like that.

## This.

**Is your main problem.**

You either didn't bother to read this error message yourself nor didn't bring it here to help us to help you.

While
there is no problem in having this file below document_root,
and there is no problem in having this file above document root either,

the only problem you have is to assign a **correct** filename.
And the error message you got could help you more than 1000 volunteers from this site.

Despite of that, you can use PHP predefined variable to make this path work from whatever part of your site. Aassuming the file is one level above the document root, the code would be

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../mysql_connect.php");
```

however, this one may produce an error too, as nobody knows a *real* file locations. Thus, you may read the error message and corect the paths. Or post it here and get an interpretation

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I actually did read the error and did research on it to find that the error was telling me it wasnt getting the correct file.  I think i found the correct answer through @sarnold  Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the database information inside your web server configuration.
If you run Apache you can use [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) inside the VirtualHost. Since you're still on a shared host, your server admin probably need to help you with this. You can read more about this approach [here](http://greg.chiaraquartet.net/another-120).

Comment: Thanks Audun!  I am actually the server admin as well.  Its a shared environment, but I am the only user.  I read the link and it is broken down very simply-- enough for a beginner!  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

> ... tried calling to it by using "../../mysql_connect.php" This is not working, it gives me an error "function not found" or something like that.

Include the connection details with:

```
require_once("../../mysql_connect.php");
```

This assumes that the file `mysql_connect.php` is two levels up from the currently executing script.

The database connection details will always be able to be read by whomever has administrative access to the server. It is not feasible to encrypt the file, because you would still need to store whatever key or password needed to decrypt it on the server as well, which would still not hide it from the server administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Besides moving out of the web-root (*which is a good step forward*) an approach I've seen used is:

```
// at the top of your index or bootstrap file
define('SECURED', true);
```

And:

```
// at the top of any file subsequently included, such as mysql_connect.php
if(!defined('SECURED'))
{
    exit();
}
```

This will at least prevent the file(s) from being accessed (*executed*) directly. This is helpful is the to-be-included files would otherwise issue a warning or error, that could potentially dump sensitive data as output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a shared hosting environment you won't be allowed access outside of document root (most likely). You will need the password therefore it won't be completely secure. Instead, you can look into creating seperate mysql users with priviledges and limiting connections to to local accesses only.

Comment: I am indeed in a shared hosting environment and have already created a separate mysql user with privileges only to the table I have made for this project.  Is this really enough?  So even if someone does in fact get my mysql user information the most they could do is... delete this particular table?  Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: LOL. no access to the document root but administrative privileges for the mysql :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: "No access to document root"? what? That is not what my answer says. It says no access *outside* document root, and I appended a *most likely* to that. Also, you are still able to create and restrict mysql user access in shared environments...

Comment: Yes, I am still able to create and restrict mysql user access, though this is on a shared server.  @Russell  -- so simply restricting the user access is enough?

Comment: @cassmoney: No. It's just another precaution :)

Answer (score 0):

i know i'm new, but something as simple as form for your login should be checked in order for it to work.

```
<form action="insertphpfilepath.php" method="POST">
```

and then in "insertphpfilepath.php", would have the mysql_query to check the login and password, not forgetting the mysql_query for connecting to the database and table using the right username and password .

a newbie recommendation to you for use mysql_real_escape_string for any $_POST['login'] so that it would become $login=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']); for evading mysql injection.

Comment: I think OP's not looking for this